# Random crashes of cocoa application

Tags: macos, debugging, crash

I have **random** crashes of my Mac OS X application and there is no  indication of a bug in my code.
How to debug such kind of bugs? I have no access to user's computer where it is randomly crashes.

Here is an example of crash log:

```
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)

Report Version:  10



Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread



Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008fe00000



VM Regions Near 0x8fe00000:
MALLOC_SMALL           0000000082000000-0000000083800000 [ 24.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

__TEXT                 000000008fe05000-000000008fe38000 [  204K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld



Application Specific Information:

objc_msgSend() selector name: _absorbDeferredNeedsDisplayRegion





Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x994d3c0b objc_msgSend + 27

1   com.apple.AppKit                0x9502985f -[_NSDisplayOperationStack exitDisplayOperationForWindow:] + 602

2   com.apple.AppKit                0x95181f8b -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 2523

3   com.apple.AppKit                0x951814fe -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:] + 167

4   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe2b6a -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 136

5   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x920e0b5f backing_callback(CGContext*, void*) + 88

6   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe1bbd CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3241

7   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe0943 CA::Layer::display_() + 1369

8   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe03e4 -[CALayer _display] + 20

9   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe03c5 CA::Layer::display() + 221

10  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe02e3 -[CALayer display] + 20

11  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fe020b CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 673

12  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fdfa84 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 38

13  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fd4cfa CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 338

14  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fd4a70 CA::Transaction::commit() + 362

15  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x91fd487d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 67

16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c7b51e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30

17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c7b45d __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 381

18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c54d85 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 405

19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c54bdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9a0ef8aa RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 242

21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9a0ef619 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 374

22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9a0ef494 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88

23  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fefa5a _DPSNextEvent + 724

24  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fef28c -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119

25  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fe56dc -[NSApplication run] + 855

26  com.apple.AppKit                0x94f888e6 NSApplicationMain + 1053

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af69ae kevent + 10

1   libdispatch.dylib               0x94e00cc5 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 993

2   libdispatch.dylib               0x94e007fd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53



Thread 2:: com.apple.CFSocket.private

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af5be6 __select + 10

1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c99320 __CFSocketManager + 1632

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918b557 _pthread_start + 344

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cee thread_start + 34



Thread 3:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af37d2 mach_msg_trap + 10

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af2cb0 mach_msg + 68

2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c4fcc9 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185

3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c556af __CFRunLoopRun + 1247

4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c54d6a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378

5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c54bdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

6   com.apple.Foundation            0x97b2ca86 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278

7   com.apple.Foundation            0x97abe8f0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76

8   [cut by author]                0x003de1dd +[HTTPServer bonjourThread] + 173

9   com.apple.Foundation            0x97b27318 -[NSThread main] + 45

10  com.apple.Foundation            0x97b2729b __NSThread__main__ + 1396

11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918b557 _pthread_start + 344

12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cee thread_start + 34



Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af37d2 mach_msg_trap + 10

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af2cb0 mach_msg + 68

2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c4fcc9 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185

3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c556af __CFRunLoopRun + 1247

4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c54d6a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378

5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98c54bdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

6   com.apple.Foundation            0x97ac329a +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 395

7   com.apple.Foundation            0x97b27318 -[NSThread main] + 45

8   com.apple.Foundation            0x97b2729b __NSThread__main__ + 1396

9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918b557 _pthread_start + 344

10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cee thread_start + 34



Thread 5:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 6:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 7:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 8:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 9:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 10:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 11:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95af60ee __workq_kernreturn + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918e04c _pthread_workq_return + 45

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9918de19 _pthread_wqthread + 448

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99175cca start_wqthread + 30



Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):

  eax: 0x818950b0  ebx: 0xac76a5d8  ecx: 0x9592966f  edx: 0x90000000

  edi: 0x8fe00000  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xbfff8c88  esp: 0xbfff8c54

   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010282  eip: 0x994d3c0b   cs: 0x0000001b

   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f

  cr2: 0x8fe00000

Logical CPU: 2
```

Comment: Are there other threads? I expect there are. Show the stack traces for those from the crash report. I'm guessing you are violating thread safety by doing something in one of those threads that you shouldn't be, so the main thread encounters inconsistent internal state.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable NSZombie (Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics)
2. Add exception breakpoint (Cmd-6, and press + button in the bottom left corner)

After that you should have better stack trace